# So we have a partner admin in our office 365 program

Tags: administration

Who handles all our new users in our office 365, and they practically handles everything. Including all users, permissions etc. in o365 and sharepoint.

We then recently hired a guy who by coincidence have handled a 365 before.

Can we just make him a global admin and let him make users etc also? Or is it ONLY the assigned partner who can do this, when one is assigned .

Thanks, sorry for bad English :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy answer - yes. Global admins have full rights to the tennant. That's everything from creating users to managing licenses and subscriptions.